# how to do one to many nested relationships using django rest framework?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here i have mentioned my model.py and serilaizers.py i want to use one to many concept here. And my expected output was like this

**Expected output**

```
  {
          "id": 1,        
          "product_name": "Rice",
          "description": "expired on 13-04-2018",
          "sales": "55",
          "cost": "55",
          "tax_details": [
                  {'id': 1, 'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/1/", 'percentage': 10},
                  {'id': 2, 'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/3/", 'percentage': 20},
                  {'id': 3, 'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/2/", 'percentage': 05},
          ... ],
      }
```

**Models.py**

**TAX model**

This is main tax table here i will mension Tax name like(IGST,GST,VAT) it was an Dropdown.

**Product**

Here it consist of product details and i have mentioned in **Expected output**

**TaxProduct**

In this model the entered taxname and percentage should store separate model.

```
  class tax(models.Model)
          tax_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
          percentage=models.CharField(max_length=250)

   class Taxproduct(models.Model):
      tax_name = ForeignKey(tax,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      percentage = models.CharField(max_length=3)

   class Product(models.Model):
      product_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
      cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)
      tax_details = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

[This is my frontend screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7oF.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7oF.png

so please tell me  how to do this?

Comment: Could you add some context on the meaning  and relationships of your products, tax products, categories and tax details ? You seem to have omitted things in your code samples.

Comment: In **Product model** consist of product details like product_name=Rice,description (when it expires), sales(selling cost), cost (buying cost) in tax_details consist of Tax name =GST(from another model that why i have mentioned as link) , percentage = it consist of tax percentage (eg '10%')  from **Taxproduct** model.

Comment: Sorry but I'm even more confused. I can definitely help you with django rest framework related stuff but you'll have to be clearer. Would it be possible to inclue a graph of your models (or a subset) in your post to clarify things ? You could use [the graph_models Django extension](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/graph_models.rst) for example.

Comment: In your `Product` model, you have a `category` field. But in your expected output, the category has disappeared from product fields and seems to be in the tax details instead ?

Comment: Thanks for reply.sorry there is no category its tax. it is an dropdown from another model. now i have clearly mention above.

Comment: Your models are a bit confusing, but I understand better. Why is there a `percentage` field in both `Tax` and `TaxProduct` ?

Comment: The Tax(model ) is main table from here only i will get default tax name and tax percentage. if i make any  changes in  tax percentage means that  changes should store in Taxproduct(Model).

Answer (score 3):

Following our discussion in comments, you need something like this:

```
class Tax(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    percentage = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class TaxProduct(models.Model):
    tax = ForeignKey(Tax, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    percentage = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                                related_name="tax_details")
```

That's roughly a many-to-many relation with a through table.

Products will have a `tax_details` field that references a Tax and its effective percentage, like you asked. And the DRF JSON output will be pretty much what you want.